# Wrong part of code executes first

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I need to get the current URL of the tab in order to parse it. I've written the following but then I run into a problem. The console.log in the last line is always run first, not the needed function. What causes this?

```js
var tabURL;
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    tabURL = tabs[0].url;
    console.log(tabURL);
});
console.log("Why does this run first?");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of asynchronous execution. While JavaScript waits for the chrome API, the console goes ahead and logs your message. To fix this, you can put a callback in a callback.

```
var tabURL;
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
   currentWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    tabURL = tabs[0].url;
    console.log(tabURL);
    console.log("I execute second!")
});
```

So as long as you put the code using the URL in the callback, it should work just fine.